# How can I limit the file size when doing a write() while writing data from a video stream in Python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I am pulling in a video stream of an unknown length and writing that file to disc using `.write()` in Python.  My basic need is to have a rolling 2-3 minutes of video recorded to that file at all times VS having that file grow to a huge size. On the other end I'm using FFMPEG to grab clips from the .dat file being written.

```
with open("./site/files/tmp/" + hashid + ".dat", 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            data = stream.read(1024)
            f.write(data)
```

Alternately if you know a way I could store that same data in memory probably only 20-50mb (2-3 mins) and send that to FFMPEG that might be an even better option as well. I'm calling FFMPEG via Popen subprocess.